# How to replace incorrect characters in a R data frame

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I'm using R to analyze a large dataset.

One of the data frames called `EssentialSum` has an error where a data is entered as `station 26 midway` instead of `station 26`.

I would like to fix this so that I can properly join this table to another one by the `Station.Name`.

I have tried a few things based on internet searches, and the attempts below did not work:

```
#using the gsub function to replace names for station 26
EssentialRep <- gsub("station 26 midway", "station 26", EssentialSum)
```

I get a weird table back for EssentialRep with only 5 records, which is not at all what I was looking for.

```
#using replace function to replace names for station 26
EssentialRep <- replace(EssentialSum, Station.Name = "station 26 midway", Station.Name = "station 26")
```

I get the error below:

> Error in replace(EssentialSum, Station.Name = "station 26 midway", Station.Name = "station 26") :
>   unused arguments (Station.Name = "station 26 midway", Station.Name = "station 26")

Comment: Please show the `dput(EssentialSum)` In the second case with `replace`, the `=` would be `==` and there is not need for `Station.Name =` in the 3rd argumenti.e. `replace(EssentialSum, Station.Name == "station 26 midway", "station 26")`

Comment: Thank you!  I get this when I try the replace option you suggested:

Comment: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "station 26") : 
  object 'Station.Name' not found

Comment: Here is the structure of EssentialSum:                                                       Telem.ID Fish.Name Date                Station.Name `n()`
  <chr>    <chr>     <dttm>              <chr>        <int>
1 20160    McKenna   2016-12-21 00:00:00 station 4        1
2 20160    McKenna   2016-12-22 00:00:00 station 4        1
3 20160    McKenna   2016-12-23 00:00:00 station 4        2
4 20160    McKenna   2016-12-23 00:00:00 station 5        2
5 20160    McKenna   2016-12-24 00:00:00 station 4        1
6 20160    McKenna   2016-12-24 00:00:00 station 5        1
>

Comment: I can do this, but the dataset has 4600 records, so dput gives a huge amount of data.  Should I still do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a copy:

```
 EssentialRep <- EssentialSum
```

The replace the values only in the column in which it appears:

```
 EssentialRep$Station.Name <- gsub("station 26 midway", "station 26", 
                                                     EssentialRep$Station.Name)
```

Your effort with `gsub` was using the entire dataframe as input, but `gsub` needs just a character vector.

The error you report in the comment `object 'Station.Name' not found` is worrisome. Makes me wonder if there is a non-printing character or space in the column name. Also worrisome is the fact taht your structure shows only four colum names but 6 datatypes. (you clearly have a "tibble", technically an object of class "tbl_df")

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment about gsub.  That worked!  There actually are 5 columns and 5 datatypes in EssentialSum- n() is a column heading.  I was trying to present the type of data in a short form by using head(EssentialSum), which resulted in the tibble.